# finding the lowest value in two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

Program that reads a *two-dimensional 10 by 10 array* of `random doubles` in the range *[0.0,100.0]* from a file.Your program will find the minimum route value from the upper left corner of the array[0][0] to the lower right corner of the array[9][9] by following the next algorithm:

1. Starting at (0,0), you can move only right or down from your current position.  The element  (0,1) is your right. The element at  (1,0) is your down.
2. Find the minimum of those two elements and and move there. By "move there" the meaning is that it will be your new position.
3. Add the minimum value to an accumulator. Keep record of your new position.
4. Look again  at the values right and down from your current position.
5. Find the minimum of those two and move there. Keep adding your minimum value to the accumulator.
6. Keep repeating steps 4) and 5) until some of the following happens:

   - If your current row is the last one, you are not allowed to move down anymore. Your only choice is to move to the right.
   - If your current column is the last one, you are not allowed to move to the right anymore, your only choice is going down.

7.If you are at the last column and the last row, you have reached the end of the array and the program ends and displays:

- The total accumulated value.-The total number of moves that you have complete going from (0,0) to (9,9)

I am stuck at the loop that prints the X every time at the lowest value
This is what I have so far. I am reading a file contents into an array

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file=new File("D:\\routes.txt");
    Scanner inputFile= new Scanner(file);

    int rows=inputFile.nextInt();
    int columns=inputFile.nextInt();

    double [][] array= new double [rows][columns];
    double lowest=array[0][0];

    for(int row=0; row <rows; row++ )
    {                
        for(int col=0; col<rows; col++)
        {
            array[row][col] =inputFile.nextDouble();
        }
    }

    printMatrix(array);   
    printPosition(array,rows,columns);
}

public static void printMatrix(double[][] M)
{
    for (int row=0; row<M.length; row++)
    {
        for(int col=0; col<M[row].length; col++)
            System.out.printf("%7.2f  ", M[row][col]);
                    System.out.println();
    }
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println();   
}

public static void printPosition(double [][]M,int y , int x)
{
    for (int row=0; row<M.length; row++)
    {
        for (int col=0; col<M[row].length;col++)
            if (col==x && row==y)
                System.out.printf("%s","  X   ");
            else
                System.out.printf("%7.2f  ",M[row][col]);
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Punctuation *might* help here but I can't tell where to add it because you wrote it as one long stream of consciousness run-on sentence (like this one).

Comment: One error i immediately see is the nested for loop in the main should be from `col < columns`

Comment: Welcome to SO. The title of your question is 'finding the lowest value' but the content seems to imply the problem is really 'finding a least-cost path'. You might need to do a bit of work clarifying what problem you are really trying to solve.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch if you can't tell where to add it what exactly was the point of adding your comment? Were you trying to help OP or just put them down and make yourself seem superior? Please try to be helpful to newcomers.

Comment: @sprinter My point was OP needs to edit the question to make it comprehensible (perhaps through proper punctuation). I cannot tell what problem OP is trying to solve, and you can't either. I want to help OP; but I can't. That makes me sad. Now the question has been edited. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is a great place to start!

Comment: I wonder why it is negative

Comment: Nice essay but your question?

Answer (score 3):

Your question lacks clarification. Anyway, assuming from a cell I can go only right and down. And route value is total cost of a path from starting cell to destination cell, need to minimize this route value. Also needs to print the path which is responsible for the `minimum` route value.

If this is what you are looking for then you can solve this very easily. Lets declare an array:

```
 dp[row][col], dp[i][j] [0 <= i < row, 0 <= j < col] //will hold the minimum route value from (0, 0) to (i, j).
```

Then `dp[row - 1][col - 1]` will be the optimal route value. You can go to `(i, j)` only from `(i - 1, j) or (i, j - 1)` considering these positions are valid.

So, `dp[i][j] = min(dp[i - 1][j], dp[i][j - 1]) + array[row][col]`, you need to handle the cases when *i - 1 or j - 1* becomes less than **0**. To print the path you need to save some information for a cell. For `(i, j)` you need to save from which cell you have come to this cell.

Now you need to print the path. Start with the destination cell, you already know from which cell you have come to it, go to that cell and same logic applies until you reach the starting cell. Now you know the path but in reverse order, just print it in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void pathFromPoint(double [][]M,int r , int c)
{
    double max = 101.0;
    int x,y;
    if (r-1>=0 && M[r-1][c]!=-1 && M[r-1][c]<max)
    {
        max = M[r-1][c];
        x=r-1;y=c;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    // Do the same for r+1,c and r,c-1 and r,c+1
    // Finally set the value of element (x,y) in the array as -1.0
    // Call pathFromPoint again with the array and x,y as r,c
    // check if r-1,r+1,c-1,c+1 is not out of the array range.
    // If you find no max, that is, if max remains as 101, just do return;
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
}
```